# It's said Docker is running on Host OS, but we still build docker file from a base image, say Ubuntu? Isn't that running OS inside docker container?

Tags: docker

For example I have used docker container which is based on Ubuntu, running on my MacOS.

Doesn't that mean the process inside docker container actually runs on a different Operating System than my host one? I am really confused by this.

Coz people say docker is light coz the application directly runs on the host OS, but in the above case isn't the application still running on the OS (ubuntu) inside the docker? And the docker file is built on top of Ubuntu base image, how is that different from a VM then?

Answer (score 0):

the docker container "service" runs based on the docker runtime environment. this docker runtime is available on many platforms.  inside of the docker container is your workload and you can put whatever you want. this is where you put your OS of your choice.